# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400 when deployed on google cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, websocket, google-cloud-platform, django-channels

I have made an app of Django Channels and its working perfect locally,but when I deployed it to production (Google Cloud Platform) it's giving me:

**(index):42 WebSocket connection to 'wss://appname-263701.appspot.com/ws/chat/user2/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400**

I can't figure whats the problem is, is it a problem of WSS? The app is working fine locally.

If need some code to review I can also upload that! Just need a guide how I can fix this

Comment: If you're using a Google Load Balancer, I had to tweak some settings there to make it work with django-channels.

Comment: No I am not using Google Load Balancer

Comment: Are you using App Engine Standard Environment?

Answer (score 5):

I think you are using Standard App Engine Environment, and WebSockets are [only supported in the Flexible Environment for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/introducing-websockets-support-for-app-engine-flexible-environment). So, I would suggest you to change the environment from Standard to Flexible, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) for the app.yaml Configuration File in Flex. This way, you will be able to use WebSockets functionality implemented on App Engine.