# WebSocket connection to 'wss://api-such.andsuch.xyz/graphql/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: django, docker-compose, graphql-subscriptions, graphene-django, graphql-playground

I recently deployed a project I'm working on to production. I use [`DjangoChannelsGraphqlWs`](https://github.com/datadvance/DjangoChannelsGraphqlWs) for GraphQL subscription functionalities. and I have GraphQL Playground set up via [`django-graphql-playground`](https://github.com/jaydenwindle/django-graphql-playground). Everything works fine locally - there are no issues whatsoever - subscriptions work fine. However, when I deployed I get the error below when I hit the Play button in Playground:

```
{
  "error": "Could not connect to websocket endpoint wss://api-such.andsuch.xyz/graphql/. Please check if the endpoint url is correct."
}
```

...and in my browser console, it says

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://api-such.andsuch.xyz/graphql/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

One thing to note is that the application is dockerized. Could it be from there? I don't think so because it works locally. Here's what my `docker-compose` file looks like:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - ./web/dev.nginx.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/dev.nginx.template
      - ./static:/static
      - ./media:/media
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - SOME_NETWORK
    command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst \"`env | awk -F = '{printf \" $$%s\", $$1}'`\" < /etc/nginx/conf.d/dev.nginx.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

  web:
    container_name: web
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    networks:
      - SOME_NETWORK
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./web:/usr/src/app/
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api-such.andsuch.xyz/graphql/
    command: bash -c /start.sh

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    networks:
      - SOME_NETWORK
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  redis:
   container_name: redis
   restart: always
   image: redis:latest
   networks:
    - SOME_NETWORK
   ports:
     - "6379:6379"
   volumes:
     - redisdata:/data

volumes:
  pgdata:
  redisdata:

networks:
  SOME_NETWORK:
    name: SOME_NETWORK
    driver: bridge
```

`settings.py`

```
...
...
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [(os.getenv('REDIS_HOST', 'redis'), os.getenv('REDIS_PORT', 6379))],
        }
    }
}
...
...
```

`routing.py`

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            path('graphql/', GraphQLWSConsumer)
        ]),
    )
})
```

`consumers.py`

```
class GraphQLWSConsumer(channels_graphql_ws.GraphqlWsConsumer):
    schema = schema

    async def on_connect(self, payload):
        self.scope['user'] = await get_user(self.scope)
```

`urls.py`

```
...
...
from graphql_playground.views import GraphQLPlaygroundView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('playground/', GraphQLPlaygroundView.as_view(
        endpoint=os.getenv('GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT'))),
]
...
```

`nginx`

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 10M; 
    
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    
    server_name api-such.andsuch.xyz;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/andsuch.xyz.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/andsuch.xyz.key;
    
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection ‘upgrade’;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
    }
}
```

What could be wrong? I'm outta ideas. Thanks!

**Update**
I checked the Network tab in chrome's developer console and discovered that websocket connections close immediately. Why is this happening?

Comment: Where did you deploy it to? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624757/error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-400-when-deployed-on has someone who deployed a Django Channels app to Google Cloud, and it turned out that not all of the Google Cloud environments support Websockets - so it might be something up with the production environment

Comment: @bouteillebleu It's DigitalOcean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through lots of articles, I discovered [Dockerizing Django with Postgres, Gunicorn, and Nginx](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/), and the section on [Nginx](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/#nginx) made me realize that the only thing that was wrong was the fact that I didn't expose port 8000 internally to other docker services.

In my `docker-compose` file, the web service was supposed to have the following, which resolved the issue.

```yaml
expose:
    - 8000
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `routing.py` file; for example:

```
from django.urls import path
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from . import consumers


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": URLRouter([
        path("api-such.andsuch.xyz/graphql/", consumers.MyGraphqlConsumer),
    ]),
})
```

While `urls.py` declares all published HTTP end-points, for other protocols (notably websockets) you should use `routing.py`, instead.

In the Consumer, which is responsible for handling all websocket events, you should immetiatly `accept` the incoming connection, since this is required by the protocol:

```
from channels.consumer import SyncConsumer

class MyGraphqlConsumer(SyncConsumer):

    def websocket_connect(self, event):
        self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.accept'
        })
```

otherwise, the connection will fail after a short timeout.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer Mario. I think the library already has that handled. The problem isn't that it fails after a short timeout. It works really well locally. The problem happens in production. Not sure why

Comment: Mhhh .. seams I misunderstood your question. Are you using Daphne for both HTTP and WebSocket traffic?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with Docker ... however, I noticed this  `ports: - "8080:80"` line in the Dockerfile for the Nginx image. Since you're using https, shouldn't you expose port 443 instead? Also, I would try with http/ws and port 80 as a preliminary step, just for testing purposes